# Flutter - Async function from a different class prints okay but returns null

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

The below function prints the proper value when called from main.dart, but returns null. It seems the function is somehow not awaiting for the value before returning.

Would appreciate some help.

location.dart

```
class Location {
  StreamSubscription<Map<String, double>> _locationSubscription;

  Future getLocation() async {
    try{
      geolocation.Location _location = new geolocation.Location();
      _locationSubscription =
          _location.onLocationChanged().listen((Map<String, double> result) {
          print(result);
          // This prints the proper value
          return(result);
          // But this returns null...

      });
    } on PlatformException {
      return null;
    } catch(e){
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

main.dart

```
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    getLocation();
  }

   getLocation() async {
    var location = Location(); 
     var loc = await location.getLocation();
     print(loc);
     //This prints null
  }
```

Comment: return _location.onLocationChanged();

Comment: @Linxy 

I'm getting the following error when trying that. 

_TypeError (type '_MapStream<dynamic, Map<String, double>>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, double>')

Comment: @pskink It only returns null once it hits platform exception, which it doesn't.

Comment: @pskink I've added the print statement, and it doesn't reach it. I'm using stream because the latest version of location package that I'm using has an issue with getLocation() and using the stream is a 
 way (albeit poor) of bypassing that. I just need to get the location once at init.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define return type of future.

```
class Location {
StreamSubscription<Map<String, double>> _locationSubscription;
 Future<Map<String, double>> getLocation() async {
 try{
      geolocation.Location _location = new geolocation.Location();
      _locationSubscription =
      _location.onLocationChanged().listen((Map<String, double> result) {
      print(result);
      // This prints the proper value
      return(result);
      // But this returns null...

     });
    } on PlatformException {
     return null;
   } catch(e){
    print(e);
   }
  }
}
```